# Slide Down Menu Appearing Outside Of Container

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following jquery slideDown menu i am trying to build. I have managed to position it to the left with a no float, however it appears the the width of it is being restricted.

http://www.pureelysium.com/PPTest

I have the following media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) 
{
    .main-nav {display:none;}
    #logobadge {margin-left: 220px; width: 185px; height: 115px;}
    #show-nav {display: block;}
    .main-nav {left: 0; margin: 0; width: auto;}
    .main-nav ul li, .main-nav ul li a 
    {
        float: none;
        width: auto; 
        background-color: #000000;
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

As well as following menu code:

```
<div class="show-nav" id="show-nav"><a href="#">Show Navigation</a>
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation"><?php wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'main-nav', 'container' => 'nav')); ?></nav>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise? As I've tried everything to make this push the content down upon click of the show navigation button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `width: auto` should likely be `width: 100%`  I tried it in dev tools and that seems to fix that problem.  Also add position relative to your nav container...entire CSS should look like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .main-nav {display:none;}
    .centering {width: 520px; margin: 0;}
    #logobadge {margin-left: 220px; width: 185px; height: 115px;}
    #show-nav {display: block;}
    .main-nav {left: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%; position: relative;}
    .main-nav ul li, .main-nav ul li a {
        float: none;
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: #000000;
        clear:both;
    }
    #serviceareawrap {width: 580px; padding: 0 15px 0 20px; }
    #contentwrap {width: 580px; padding: 0 15px 0 20px;}
    .newstitle {display: none;}
    #innermaincontent {padding: 0;}
    #innermaincontent, #recentpostswrap, #footerinner {width: 580px; border: none; float: left;}
    #serviceareawrap #area1, #serviceareawrap #area2, #serviceareawrap #area3, #serviceareawrap #area4 {width: 135px;}
    #footerarea1 {float: left; width: 200px; padding: 5px 10px;}
    #footerarea2 {float: right; width: 200px; padding: 5px 10px; min-height: 225px; text-align: right;}
    #footerarea3 {float: left;  width: 200px; margin-top: 20px;}
    #footerarea4 {float: right;  width: 200px; padding: 5px 10px; text-align: right;}
    #footerarea5 {float: left;  width: 200px; padding: 5px 10px; height: 50px!important;}
    #socialicons {width: 580px; padding-left: 15px;}

}
```

Comment: nope :( it didnt work for me, i want the colour to stretch across the screen, similiar to an accordian menu. I really wanted it to put the content down but that didnt work neither ha

Comment: @KirstyHarris that width: 100% needs to be on .main-nav as well...  .main-nav {left: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%;}

Comment: Also, you have a height set on your "Show Navigation" container of 50px...so it won't expand to fit. If you take that height off and add position relative to your menu .main-nav it should all work.

Comment: @KirstyHarris no problem...glad to help out. If the answer is correct, would you mind accepting it so others know the question is resolved? Cheers!